# How to convert an IQueryable<T> to a List<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

Just learning LINQ and i've come to a newbie roadblock in my test project. Can you explain what i'm doing wrong?

```
public List<ToDoListInfo> retrieveLists(int UserID)
{
//Integrate userid specification later - need to add listUser table first
IQueryable<ToDoListInfo> lists = 
    from l in db.ToDoLists
    select new ToDoListInfo { 
        ListID = l.ListID, 
        ListName = l.ListName, 
        Order = l.Order, 
        Completed = l.Completed 
    };

    return lists.ToList<ToDoListInfo>;
}
```

I'm getting an error saying the following:

> Cannont convert method group 'ToList' to non-delegate type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' Do you intend to
>   invoke the method?

Comment: the clue was in "Do you intend to invoke the method?"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You just need parantheses:

`lists.ToList<ToDoListInfo>();`

Also, you do not have to declare the type parameter, i.e. you could use the following and let the type-system infer the type parameter:

`lists.ToList();`

Comment: Declaring the type name parameter might actually be a *bad* thing here, as you have to match the type parameter of the `lists` `IEnumerable<T>` implementation, which could cause a compile-time error; better to let [type-inference](http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2007/04/06/111034.aspx) do it's job

Comment: What if I want to convert the iqueryble collection to a different type of list? For example lets assume I have two class A & B with almost similar signature. Now I retrieve data from A & want make a list of type B, how can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You are just missing the closing brackets on ToList, should be:

```
 ToList();
```

or

```
ToList<ToDoListInfo>();
```